# Multiple rows value change in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using below code to select multi-select value change. I have two buttons (Yes & No). In this code "yes" functionality works fine, but when I select multiple rows and click "No" button it doesn't work.

```
if (isset($_POST['row_id_to_change_value']))
{
    $files_array = explode(",", $_POST['row_id_to_change_value'][0]);
    $count = count($files_array);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++)
    {
        if ($files_array[$i] > 0)
        {
            $show = htmlentities($_POST['file_show']);
            update_post_meta($files_array[$i], 'file_show_to_customer', $show);
            $show == 'yes' ? $showing = 'show' : $showing = 'hide';
            $updated = get_the_title($files_array[$i]) . ' has been updated to <strong>' . show . '</strong>.';
            wp_redirect(get_permalink() . '?show=1');
        }
    }
}
```

Html Part

```
<div id="change-visibility-dialog-multiple" style="display:none;">
   <form method="post" action="">
    <h4>Change the customer's visibility:</h4>
     <input type="hidden" name="row_id_to_change_value[]" value="" />
      <button class="button-dark" name="file_show" value="no">No<i class="btl bt-ban"></i></button>
      <button class="button-submit" name="file_show" value="yes">Yes</button>
   </form>
 </div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `$showing = ($show == 'yes') ? 'show' : 'hide';` Try changing the third line inside your second if statement to that.

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball OP's ternany statement is valid as-is.

Comment: Should `wp_redirect(get_permalink() . '?show=1');` be changed to `wp_redirect(get_permalink() . '?show='.($show == 'yes' ? '1' : '0'));`?

Comment: FYI, there is a typo in the snippet: `…<strong>' . show . '</strong>…`. Shoud be `$show` or `$showing`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working